# Instantiate a field level HashMap in JCodeModel

Tags: jcodemodel

I want to declare and instantiate a HashMap in one go in JCodeModel.

I do:

```
jc.field(JMod.PRIVATE, HashMap.class, "initAttributes");
```

which declares it but doesn't instantiate it. How do I instantiate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the simplest case, you can just append the initialization directly to your creation of the field:

```
jc.field(JMod.PRIVATE, HashMap.class, "initAttributes")
    .init(JExpr._new(codeModel.ref(HashMap.class)));
```

Some further hints:

- Considering that you should usually [program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface), it is a good practice to declare the variable using a type that is "as basic as possible". You should hardly **ever** declare a variable as

  ```
  private HashMap map;
  ```

  but basically always only as

  ```
  private Map map;
  ```

  because `Map` is the interface that is relevant here.
- You can also add *generics*  in JCodeModel. These usually involve some calls to `narrow` on certain types. It is a bit more effort, but it will generate code that can be compiled without causing warnings due to the raw types.

An example is shown here. (It uses `String` as the key type and `Integer` as the value type of the map. You may adjust this accordingly)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.sun.codemodel.CodeWriter;
import com.sun.codemodel.JClass;
import com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel;
import com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass;
import com.sun.codemodel.JExpr;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMod;
import com.sun.codemodel.writer.SingleStreamCodeWriter;

public class InitializeFieldInCodeModel
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();
        JDefinedClass definedClass = codeModel._class("com.example.Example");

        JClass keyType = codeModel.ref(String.class);
        JClass valueType = codeModel.ref(Integer.class);
        JClass mapClass = 
            codeModel.ref(Map.class).narrow(keyType, valueType);
        JClass hashMapClass =
            codeModel.ref(HashMap.class).narrow(keyType, valueType);
        definedClass.field(JMod.PRIVATE, mapClass, "initAttributes")
            .init(JExpr._new(hashMapClass));

        CodeWriter codeWriter = new SingleStreamCodeWriter(System.out);
        codeModel.build(codeWriter);
    }

}
```

The generated class looks as follows:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {

    private Map<String, Integer> initAttributes = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

}
```